# How to modify every bash command before execution?

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a way to modify every command that is entered at the bash prompt with a script/hook?

In my ideal world, the script would fire after the user has entered the command but BEFORE the Enter key is pressed. It would get the command string as a parameter, modifiy it and hand it over to bash for executing (so everything would happen transparently).

I would use this hook for some company-specific substitutions which cannot be done using aliases, but above all I'm interested if this can be done.

I know of some hacks to do something with the last command after it has been executed (`trap 'function' DEBUG` and the like) as there are a lot of questions concerning that scenario but this is of no help here.

Thanks and kind regards!

Comment: Can you give an example why this would be useful in your environment? I would not be comfortable with anyone mangling with what I enter into my prompt, especially if I don't know what happens to the command.

Comment: @Barmar This is exactly what I meant. Of course there is no way to tell when the user is about to press the Enter key.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth I can absolutely understand your point - I would not want anyone to sit between what I enter and what gets executed. But since I'm doing that to my own shell, I can live with it.

Comment: @Michael Trojanek Aye! So this should just apply to your shell on one particular box? Can you give some simplified use cases nonetheless?

Comment: One example that comes to my mind is accessing multihomed hosts in a network. So `ssh somehost` would expand to `ssh somehost.subdomain1` (subdomain1 could be a management domain) but `mount somehost ...` would expand to `mount somehost.subdomain2 ...` (trivial example).

Comment: I see. How would wrapping ssh/mount to change the host parameter not solve the problem though (as stated per your question)?. Another approach could use bash completion to conditionally expand the host parameter based on the typed command before.

Comment: For this use case, this is what I do at the moment - I wrote a wrapper for `ssh` and `scp` which substitutes and hands over the edited command line to the ssh/scp command.

Comment: Let me give you another use case : I often forget to run mysql before running commands like 'SELECT * FROM my_table;' ...
It would be great to have such a request executed automatically.
(I've got a 'mymysql' command that launch mysql on the correct database - but this is far beyond the point here).
Aliases or functions are not an answer : if the command is not reinterpreted, the * would be expanded to the list of files in the current dir. Enjoy the challenge !

Comment: Challenge is double : moreover, "select" is a built-in...

Comment: For the ssh case, btw, you can configure aliases (hostname X really means Y, with config options Z1, Z2 and Z3 set) in `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: ...anyhow, you *could* do what you were asking for here with a DEBUG trap, but it strikes me as a sufficiently painful and convoluted approach that I'm not much inclined to get involved in assisting. (The usual, and I'd argue saner, answers involve the `command_not_found` hook, and individual function wrappers for specific commands that you want to override/patch/etc).

Answer (score 3):

What you want is a kind of command completion -- it seems to me.

There is a  lot behind bash line editing: bindable readline commands, or command completion and command substitution.

First off you can write write and compile your own bash builtins:
http://www.drdobbs.com/shell-corner-bash-dynamically-loadable-b/199102950

Next, you can alter bash through what people call edit line or readline:
Start here maybe:
http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/features_7.html

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Line-Editing.html